# how to make the app which hide the phone apps with Flutter

Tags: hide

Im trying to make the application which is used to hide the application the phone applications with using the flutter. How to make this with flutter. Answers

Answer (score 0):

use wechat_assets_picker: package . It will help you to pick the exact/original path. After getting the original path now you can do any sort of operation easily! You can read /write on external storage for further operations